# How many ADS1115 ADCs can I connect to a single Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c, adc

I know we can connect 4 [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf)s to an Arduino Mega 2560.

Is there any limit on the number of ADS1115s we can connect to the Mega giving each a different address? I have to connect at least 36 ADS1115s.

Comment: you could try connecting all 36 ... pull one of 36 address lines high and talk to that one selected device

Answer (score 1):

256(+?)

With 8 [TCA9548A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf?ts=1639975466543) 1-to-8 I2C Multiplexers on different I2C addresses, it is a multiplication problem: You can expand the Arduino Mega's I2C port on Digital Pins 20&21 to 8 multiplexers *  8 multiplexer ports * 8 ADS1115 addresses to 256.

It might be possible to go much further if you can wire and code multiple levels of multiplexers.